# How to wait for controller function to finish using sinon.js and Express in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, sinon, sinon-chai

I'm trying to write a unit test for one of my Express controller functions, however, the sinon calls don't wait for the controller function to finish. Do I need to write the controller function as async so I can await in the test?

```
it('should allow creating', function (done) {
      const req = {
        body: {
          name: 'something here',
          isPrivate: 'true',
        },
        flash: sinon.spy(),
        user: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId() }
      };
      const res = {
        redirect: sinon.spy()
      }

      leagueController.create(req, res);        
      req.flash.calledWith('success', 'League created').should.be.true;
      res.redirect.calledWith('/leagues').should.be.true;
      League.findOne({ name: 'something here' }, (err, league) => {
        should.exist(league);
        done();
      });      
    });
```

Here is a simplified controller function:

```
function create(req, res) {
  const { name, isPrivate } = req.body;
  let newLeague = new League({
    name: name,
    isPrivate: isPrivate,
  });
  newLeague.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      req.flash('error', err.message || err);
      debug(err.message);
      return res.redirect('/leagues/new');
    }
    req.flash('success', 'League created');
    debug('league created');
    return res.redirect('/leagues');
  });
}
```

Comment: *Do I need to write the controller function as async so I can await in the test* - Yes

Comment: Did you try making the function that you pass to the test `async`?

Comment: You need to show the code of the controller. Please create a minimal, reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

If your controller isn't actually sending a network request (which I hope not in a unit test) , easiest way here would be to use [`fake-timers`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.6/fake-timers/) and do a small `clock.tick(50)`.

If it actually does something asynchronous, then best way would be to return a promise from `newLeague.save`